# How to get file that is calling function

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I have this global function in my main app file

```js
  async getTip(){
    const tipschema = require('./schemas/tipschema')
    const tipschemas = await tipschema.find()
        const randomschema = tipschemas[Math.floor(Math.random()*tipschemas.length)]
        const randomtip = randomschema.tip
        return randomtip
  },
```

Is there any way I can get the file name that is calling the function?
For example:

```js
  async getTip(){
const file = await req.file // example of what I'm trying to do
  },
```

thanks

Comment: Why is it necessary…?

Comment: JavaScript is a parsed language. Once it's compiled into the JavaScript runtime, "files" are meaningless. The calling function might have been `eval`ed, passed to the Function constructor as a string or a packaging tool like webpack might have packed several module together into one chunk. If you need schema, etc, pass it along to the function as a context argument. It's much easier to test and resilient to packaging, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
function getTip() {
   let caller = getTip.caller;
}
```

BUT this is depricated. Look also here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

Also note that this is not working with strict mode.